# Motor voltage increases as current decreases?

Tags: voltage, current, motor

I was looking into a motor characteristics from a youtube video and i noticed that as the voltage applied increases(fans speed faster) the current decreases. Considering the motor load is constant( not sure about this) why does this happen? isn't voltage supposed to be proportional to current?

[image]

Comment: Voltage is proportional to current in resistors. Are motors resistors?

Comment: For something like a simple resistor, yes. For something with aerodynamics involved, it gets much more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the load power is constant (as you suggest) then, as speed increases, torque decreases because load power is proportional to speed × torque. If driven by an ideal DC motor, when the motor supply voltage increases, load speed must also increase (fundamental to DC motors) and, torque has to decrease (load power constant) therefore motor current MUST decrease (again, fundamental to DC motors).

Answer (score 0):

The current drawn by a dc motor is proportional to the torque applied to the load.

The torque is used in two ways:

1. Accelerating the inertial load. The higher the acceleration, the higher the torque. So the current increases with acceleration. When a steady speed is maintained, the current drops to zero (ideally).
2. Overcoming friction. The torque required to overcome friction is proportional to the speed. So current will be drawn when spinning is constant.

The total current is the sum of these two effects.

You can experience a similar action while driving a car. While accelerating up to speed the “gas pedal” is pressed to get the desired acceleration. When the cruising speed is reached the pedal is “backed off” to stop accelerating but pressed a small amount to maintain speed.